# SSRS Email Symbol in Footer of report

Tags: reporting-services, footer, ssrs-2016

Could be a rather trivial question, but how does one put an E-mail Symbol next to the email address in the footer of an SSRS 2016 Report please? I've tried HTML Code like ✉ (&#9993) but it doesn't work ( in reporting services) .. it just shows it as &#9993 even when the markup type is HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a placeholder and then use an asterisk `*` in `Wingdings` font which will give you an envelope symbol.

1. Create text box
2. Click to select it, then click again to set the cursor inside the text box
3. Type your `*` and format as WingDings
4. Add some spaces if required then
5. Right-Click in the text box and choose `create placeholder`
6. Set the placeholder expression to whatever you like (an email address I assume)
7. Format the placeholder as you wish (different font etc)

Alternatively, you could just the the  `@` symbol... but where's the fun in that? :)

Comment: Thanks @Alan .. should have given the full story. The footer is a text box that has information that relates to a company (a separate DataSet. It has only one expression.. as such, I don't want to break it up into separate text boxes and make it messy. Any chance of a character set that would achieve the same? .. yes, already have @.. but where ya.. where is the fun / challenge in that!

Comment: It won;t be separate text boxes, it will be two bits of text in the the same text box. I chose wingdings because it's pretty common.